# how to load parsed data into an existing textview(existing layout) in android

Tags: android, parsing, textview

hii every buddy ,
am not getting  how to load parsed data into an existing textview(existing layout) in android,
insted of loading data to the new textview like how they r doing in the following tutorial(check the following link)

[check this link for tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser/)

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial they do:

```
TextView something = new TextView(context);
```

As you don't want to do so (good decision), you get the reference to the existent `TextView`:

```
TextView something = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.the_id_you_gave_it_in_the_xml);
// then:
something.setText(theParsedString);
```

Comment: thanx for ur reply,,ya i tried this but i didnt get,bcoz we r declaring textview array so am unable to load to existing textview

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using existing Layout

```
Textview name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String txt="";
        for(int i=0;i<sitesList.getName().size();i++)
        {
             txt=txt+sitesList.getName().get(i).toString();


        }
name.setText(txt);
```

Comment: i tried but its crashing,can u download that tutorial n modify n give me,? please

Comment: hii parag, sorry to disturb u, again i got some error,,,i implimented ur logic in my code , i hav written in the same way how u r written , but its crashing when controller enters the for loop,,can u sujest me y its happening so

Comment: i send the sample for Parsing but using  SAXParser Try it

Comment: no,, parsed contents r displaying in new layout,,but when i loaded that to existing layout(like how u did) its not executing

Comment: after launching goto  usermenu> next> click on any list row >  click on any list row,  u ill get parsed data

Answer (score -1):

Sowmya It seems that you are creating multiple textviews & trying to update those textviews .In that case you need to use [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) .

There is an example you can find [here](http://jongladwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/androidsettag-and-gettag-usage-for.html)

Regarding your answer:

> we r declaring textview array so am
>   unable to load to existing textview

I have never implemented such a textview array instead the best practice would be to

```
    for (String s : stringarray) {
          TextView tv = new TextView (this);
          tv.setText(s);
          tv.setTag("1");
         linearlayout.addView(tv);
        }
```

***EDIT:***For those enthusiast out there I found 2 more methods:

One is using [setId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) to manually set ID of that textview & then find it by [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29)

Another method(is though not implemented by me , but is a suggestion by my colleague so dont kill me if it doesn't works) is to store textview objects in an arraylist & then access them & do whatever you want whoa!